# An empty relation on a non-empty set -- can it be an equivalence relation?

Tags: equivalence-relations

Given a non-empty set, A, and an empty relation, R, on that set A, can it be the case that the relation R is an equivalence class?

Transitivity. (a,b) in R, (b,c) in R ===> (c,a) in R. This is trivially true because there is no a, b, c, in R, so the implication is true by way of the antecedent being false.

Symmetry. (a,b) in R ==> (b,a) in R. Again, trivially, the implication is true because the antecedent is false.

But what about reflexivity. If a in R, then a in R. But no a in R -- is this true or false?

Comment: I believe reflexivity is equivalent to the condition that $\forall a\in A (\exists b\in A, (a,b) \in R) \implies (a,a) \in R$ This is vacuously true.

Comment: Reflexivity is $\bigl(\forall a\bigr)\bigl((a,a)\in R\bigr)$.

Comment: Agreeing with @DanielFischer's definition, in which case the empty relation is not an equivalence relation.  If you take ruler501's definition, then it is an equivalence relation, but I don't think this definition is standard.  Either way, "If a is in R, then a is in R", doesn't make sense as a definition of reflexivity for two reasons: first, it seems like you mean a to be an element of A, in which case it can't also be an element of $R$.  And second, the statement "if x, then x" is always true.  Always.  It doesn't need a name like "reflexivity".

Comment: I'm not sure if my definition is right or not it just seemed the closest to what he had said that made logical sense.

Answer (score 6):

An equivalence relation on a non empty set can't be empty, because it's reflexive. So, for any $a\in A$, you have $(a,a)\in R$. Now there *is* some $a\in A$.

From a slightly different point of view, an equivalence relation on $A$ always contains the identity relation
$$
\Delta_A=\{(a,a):a\in A\}
$$
which is empty if and only if $A$ is empty.

It's true that the empty relation is transitive and symmetric (also antisymmetric, by the way) on every set.

---

Note that the main purpose of equivalence relations is to partition the set into pairwise disjoint subsets:
$$
[a]_R=\{x\in A: (a,x)\in R\}
$$
and so reflexivity (hence non emptyness of $R$) is essential to have $a\in[a]_R$. With the empty relation you can't have a partition defined this way.